# How to write the DABR register of PowerPc in assembly language?

Tags: linux, breakpoints, cpu-registers, powerpc, instructions

I need to find out what overwrote a global variable on my PowerPC/Linux accidentally, using the DABR register. What's the instruction that writes the DABR register? Is that instruction allowed to be executed in the userland?

Answer (score 1):

You can write the `DABR` (Data Address Breakpoint Register) via `SPR` (Special Purpose Register) **1013** using the "*Move to Special-Purpose Register*" instruction.

#### Example

The following code *moves* the contents of `r0` into the `DABR`:

```
mtspr 1013, r0
```

> This register is accessible to **supervisor-level** software only (supervisor level is referred to as **privileged** state in the architecture specification).

#### References

[Programming Environments Manual for 32-Bit Implementations of the PowerPC™ Architecture](http://www.nxp.com/docs/en/reference-manual/MPCFPE32B.pdf)